# Table with programmatically specified number of iterators in Compile

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation, compile

Compare two ways of computing a table of values of a multivariable Gaussian:

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  ta = Table[Exp[-Total[Array[r, 5]^2]],
  {r[1], 1., 2.},
  {r[2], 1., 3.},
  {r[3], 1., 3.},
  {r[4], 1., 23.},
  {r[5], 1., 421.}
  ];
]
(* 2.1069 *)

comp = Compile[{},
  Table[Exp[-(r[1]^2 + r[2]^2 + r[3]^2 + r[4]^2 + r[5]^2)],
  {r[1], 1., 2.},
  {r[2], 1., 3.},
  {r[3], 1., 3.},
  {r[4], 1., 23.},
  {r[5], 1., 421.}
  ], CompilationTarget->"C"
];
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  tb = comp[];
]
(* 0.002853 *)
```

I would like to get such a speedup in a case where I specify the number of iterators/variables programmatically, and where the iterator values are stored in a list `itvals`. Non-compiled is easy, e.g.:

```
n = 5; (* number of iterators *)
itvals = RandomReal[{0,1}, {n, 8}];
tc = Fold[Table[#1,{r[#2],itvals[[#2]]}]&, Exp[-Total[Array[r,n]^2]], Range[n]];
```

Or:

```
td = Table[Exp[-Total[Array[r,n]^2]],##] & @@ Table[{r[i], itvals[[i]]}, {i,n,1,-1}];

tc == td
(* True *)
```

But I can't get this to work inside `Compile`! If I try

```
c1 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
  Block[{itvals},
   itvals = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 5}];
   Fold[Table[#1, {x[#2], itvals[[#2]]}] &, 1, Range[n]]
   ]
  ]
```

where I use the "function" 1 instead of the Gaussian for simplicity. `CompilePrint[c1]` shows that the whole `Fold` is wrapped in a `MainEvaluate`. I can't do it similarly to `td` either because `Compile` only supports `@@` with the functions `Plus`, `Times` or `List`...

Anybody know a way to do it?

Comment: Could you show the code you attempted as your compiled version?

Comment: @MarcoB, I've added it.

Answer (score 6):

Verily, this is a headache, since `Table` wants its iterators as  Sequence rather than nested list of lists. Here is a method I used quite recently to get sufficiently fast code [for this](https://oeis.org/A272658).

```
c1c[n_] := 
 With[{itvals = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 5}]}, 
  With[{iters = Apply[Sequence, Table[{x[j], itvals[[j]]}, {j, n}]]},
   c1[n] = cCompile[{},
      tTable[1, iters]] /. {cCompile -> Compile, tTable -> Table}]]

In[55]:= c1c[2][]

(* Out[55]= {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1,
   1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}} *)
```

Comment: This looks promising! I can see that each list on level 1 of `itvals` gets copied at the start of the compiled code, which seems unnecessary. But since it only happends once at the start and each element of `itvals` is short, it should not matter, right?

Comment: As a side question, do you know why `tc` with `Fold` evaluates much faster than `td` with iterators spliced in? I had not expected that.

Comment: I do not know why the `Fold` multi-iterator is faster. I had not done a time test and I confess I would not have expected that. Maybe related to your observation about the list copying?

Comment: I figured it out, it was simply a matter of how long the body of the `Table` was held. In the `Fold` case, the Gaussian is evaluated as soon as the iterator in the innermost `Table` has a value, and the inner `Table` has elements like `Exp[-0.527 - r[2]^2 - r[3]^2 - ...]`. This gets passed as the body to the next step in the `Fold`. OTOH when splicing in, the body is held all the way, so for each set of iterator values it has to turn `Exp[-Total[Array[r,n]^2]]` into `Exp[-r[1]^2-r[2]^2-...]` before inserting values. Simply wrapping the body of `td` in `Evaluate` made it faster than `tc`.

Comment: Ah. Nice detective work.